# Clarification on the Onion architecture's Domain Service and Application Service

Tags: domain-driven-design, layers, service, onion-architecture

I am studying Onion Architeture but i got some doubts:

All the samples (github) I found over internet are too simple, or are implemented under DDD (which I have not studied at the moment) so I can not get a clear concept.

About **Domain.Services** I have some doubts:

1. It has to define implementations?  For all Services interfaces declared?
2. It has to define domain logic, can you give a detailed example? (avoid tipical GetUser() example ). I can imagine this service as for example

   ```
    public interface IMarketKartService  
    {
       double AddItemToKart(Kart kart, ShopItem item);  
       double CalculateBill(Kart kart); 
    }
   ```
3. This layer is able to use repositories or not?

Later is **Application.Services** layer. As i read it should be an API, and implement user cases that get consumed by the User (for example from a WinForms app)

4. Am I right?
5. Is this layer able to use repositories? (I suposse that yes but please clarify) So repositories in which layers are eligible to use?

I don't get the sense of many DDD terms, so please avoid them in your explanations.

Comment: Maybe (correct me if I'm wrong) you have a misconception here: with Onion you do not have insulated layers. Application may (and should) access domain model and you do not duplicate in service layer what you already have in the domain (to answer #2). About #3 and #5: each outer layer can use ANY inner layer (not only the immediate one). This should also answer to #1: unless specific implementation requirements impose otherwise then yes. In this layer you expose interfaces and it contains also their implementations (ADDING on the top of the domain, do not replacing it).

Comment: About my last sentence: well...of course there are corner cases. For example a service may expose an interface tuned for network operations (which is obviously different because of network latency and response time then you have to optimize the number of requests). In this case some level of _duplication_ is unavoidable.

Comment: So , my Domain.Service layer could have implementatios  and use Repos?

Comment: Your service layer SHOULD have implementations (otherwise...where implementation is defined? If it's implemented directly in domain model then caller MUST access directly the domain model). Let me repeat: unless you're making an optimized service to optimize network requests then UI (for example) can access domain, no need to wrap each _layer_. About repos: yes, repository returns domain objects then it can be well accessed from services. Just do not make the mistake to create a service layer which just forward all calls to repository: it's useless and unnecessary. This is where Onion differs.

Comment: So what are the sense for application services to exists? If all the domain logic is inside the domain layer. I read that they  orchestarte the domain.services usage ? is that right ? Please give an example . Many thanks  @AdrianoRepetti

Comment: Domain model should...describe the domain. For example in a _typical_ LOB on-line shopping you will have `Cart`, `Product`, `Order` and so on. All the business logic says there. What's a service for? 1) To simplify use-cases: when placing an `Order` you may want to perform other operations (for example to check if product is currently available and if not then order one) or - probably - 2) interact with external services (for example calling the payment processing provider for pre-authorization.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb (for me) when I have to interact with anything else but the domain model then I need a service. Note that I (maybe wrongly?) put TWO kind of services in the _service layer_: use-cases (you may call it _Facade_) and services which abstract external services (which do not belong to my domain model like payment processing provider in the previous example). I put facades in the service layer because it's also the place I put services which access domain model with a different interface (again...for example when I want a coarser interface to optimize network access)

Comment: Last note: why case 1) is inside service instead of domain? Because then I am free to access other service and interact with external entities (something you avoid in the domain model)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, you are great with your help and I can get some concepts from your answers but I get some trouble understanding you. WHen you say "service" you mean application service or domain service? Please , it will be awesome if you edit the comments and clarify it, because it is the main target of my question

Comment: You say that all the logic resides in domain model. But you put all the logic inside Order, Cart, Profuct? Or you define domain services that contains the logic?? This is the point where I have a good explanation, with concrete details . Many thanks

Comment: The idea is to make sure that all of the dependencies in your project are pointing "inward" towards your domain (i.e. the place where all business logic resides). This makes sense right? You want all of your business logic in one place (domain), and you want every other piece of your application to depend on this place in order to carry out logic. With that in mind, it should be clear that the logic needs to reside in `Order`, `Cart`, `Product`, etc.

Comment: For example, say you have a rule that says no `Cart` can have a total bill of `> $25000`. If, in your top-level Application Service, you have some logic like `if( cart.total < 25000) { cart.addItem(item) } else { throw }`, you now have a problem. This logic is not portable. That is, some other place in your application could be adding `Items` to your `Cart` according to different rules. BUT, if that logic resides in the `Cart.addItem()` method, it's impossible for this invariant to occur. That's the point. I suggest you familiarize yourself with DDD. It will help you going forward.

Comment: But I read that domain entities should be POCOs , how do you fit you statement with that?@king-side-slide

Comment: What about my statement indicates to you that the domain entities mustn't be POCOs?

Comment: @king-side-slide I read that in onion architecture recommendations, is that a bad rule?

Comment: @Badulake Domain entities should be POCOs. Why do you think I am recommending something else? I don't see how my simple example would lead to that conclusion.

Comment: @king-side-slide if( cart.total < 25000) { cart.addItem(item) } else { throw } that method is adding an item to a POCO. Or am I getting confused?Where will you put that code?

Comment: @Badulake I think you may be misunderstanding the term "POCO". The term is used to indicate that the object doesn't have external dependencies. Not that it is devoid of behavior. It's to facilitate loose coupling. Domain entities are where *all* behavior should be located. Application Services simply coordinate that behavior for a business use-case (i.e. act as a consumer of the domain's API).

Comment: @king-side-slide  how can I ask you some questions in a chat style?email? Many thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81410/discussion-between-king-side-slide-and-badulake).